# Set Debugger Language Exception (to ignore) in Build Configuration

Tags: delphi, debugging, exception

In Tools | Options | Debugger Options | Language Exceptions it's possible to ignore specific Exception types. Is it possible to do define this per project? 
Eg in the Debug Build Configuration (Delphi 2009 and/or 2010)?

/Edit: [Reported in QC](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=82037)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  That would be a very nice option to have, though.  I can think of plenty of places where it would be useful.  Why don't you submit it to QC as a feature request?

Comment: I was afraid that this was indeed not possible...
I will wait to see if someone finds a way or trick and if not I will accept this answer and submit to QC as well.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is the same way (although worse in my opinion).  It would be a nice feature though to be able to specify that at the project level.